# logstash kafka output ( sending json data )

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

In logstash, i am trying to send the data to kafka as well as ES. In ES, the data is sent in the same format as shown by rubydebug ( basically json data after applying filters and adding new field). I want to send the same data to kafka. But logstash sends only the original message to kafka. ( i am not modiying the original message).

Is it possible to send the same data to kafka ( json format) which we send it to ES ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `codec => "json"` on your `kafka {}` output will likely give you what you are looking for. The default is 'plain', which doesn't do any formatting.